# How to deduct total after removing an item in list box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two list boxes.

The first listbox has a pre loaded items once An item selected from `lbmenu` will be displayed in `lborder` and the price was inputted through a text box and the total will be updated depending on the price inputted.

My problem was in removing items I want to update the total once an item was remove in `lborder`.

This is my code

```
namespace WinFormsApp1

{

    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {

        public Form1()

        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            lborder.Items.Add(lbmenu.SelectedItem + " = P" + txtprice.Text);

            double total = 0;

            total = double.Parse(txttp.Text) + double.Parse(txtprice.Text);

            txttp.Text = total.ToString();

            txtprice.Clear();

            txtprice.Focus();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            lborder.Items.RemoveAt(lborder.SelectedIndex);

                 double total = 0;

            total = double.Parse(txttp.Text) - double.Parse(txtprice.Text);

            txttp.Text = total.ToString();

            txtprice.Clear();

            txtprice.Focus();

        }   

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            txtprice.Clear();

            txttp.Clear();

            lborder.Items.Clear();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I can’t understand what you’re asking. Can you change the text in the question to refer to the actual list box names?

Comment: Listbox1(lbmenu) and listbox2(lborder)

Comment: You’re not using (as far as I can see) any kind of data representation so when you remove the item you have no way of knowing what the total is? Rather then directly adding and removing, I’d suggest keeping an underlying list of items, from which you can calculate the total when it’s are added or removed.